# Cypress can't get variables from process.env file

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, cypress

I've got a problem with getting variables value from process.env file in my cypress test. I try to do it according to this: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-5-Plugins
But I get undefined error when I try to use varaibles from prcess env file

My index.js file:

```js
const { preprocessTypescript } = require('@nrwl/cypress/plugins/preprocessor');
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', preprocessTypescript(config));
  
  [
    'DB_USER',
    'DB_PASS',
    'DB_SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT',
    'DB_SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE',
    'DB_SNOWFLAKE_ROLE',
    'DB_SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA',
    'DB_SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE'
  ].forEach(v => {
    config.env[v] = process.env[v];
  });

  return config;
};
```

process.env file (in root folder)

```js
DB_SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT=www.xyz.com
DB_USER=xyzxyz
DB_PASS=xyzxyzxyz
DB_SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE=XYZX
```

and test.spec.ts

```js
  const snowflakeUrl: string = Cypress.env('DB_SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT');
  const userName: string = Cypress.env('DB_USER');
  const password: string = Cypress.env('DB_PASS');
  const database: string = Cypress.env('DB_SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE');
```

Comment: Is your file named `process.env` or `.env`, because I think it should be the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename should be `.env`, that's what [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme) works with.

It then loads environment variables into `process.env` object.